# Unreal 4.24: Adding value to TMap in the Delegate callback method crashes Editor

Tags: c++, delegates, unreal-engine4

**[UPDATE**(After the Bug was resolved)**]**

The crash was caused by the fact that I was referring to the dictionary after the object (which the dictionary was private variable of) was destroyed. The initial idea that the crash is caused because of issues related to multithreading in the callback was untrue.

**What I am trying to do:**

Download image data from URL and add it to Dictionary

`TMap<FString, TArray<uint8>> URLToImageTArrayDictionary ;`

**What is working:**

Assigning Dictionary values on Game-Thread works fine. Forex.

```
FString key = "key";
TArray<uint8> IntArray;
IntArray.Init(10, 5);
URLToImageTArrayDictionary.Add(key, IntArray); //No Problem
```

**What is not working:** Calling .Add(key, value) from a parallel thread via a Delegate.

```
DownloadTexturesFromURLs()
{    
    TSharedRef<IHttpRequest> ThumbRequest = FHttpModule::Get().CreateRequest();
    ThumbRequest->SetVerb("GET");
    ThumbRequest->SetURL(URL);
    ThumbRequest->OnProcessRequestComplete().BindRaw(this, &DataTransfer::OnImageDataReceived);
    ThumbRequest->ProcessRequest();
}

OnImageDataReceived(FHttpRequestPtr Request, FHttpResponsePtr Response, bool bWasSuccessful)
{
    if (bWasSuccessful && Response.IsValid())
    {
        FString key = "key";
        TArray<uint8> IntArray;
        IntArray.Init(10, 5);
        URLToImageTArrayDictionary.Add(key, IntArray); //This crashes with error given log
    }
}
```

**Crash Logs:**

```
    [2020.05.18-12.43.39:871][658]LogWindows: Windows GetLastError: The operation completed successfully. (0) 
[2020.05.18-12.43.42:274][658]LogWindows: Error: === Critical error:
    === 
[2020.05.18-12.43.42:274][658]LogWindows: Error:  
[2020.05.18-12.43.42:274][658]LogWindows: Error: Assertion failed: Index>=0 && Index<NumBits [File:C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.24\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Containers/BitArray.h] [Line: 737]  
[2020.05.18-12.43.42:274][658]LogWindows: Error:  
[2020.05.18-12.43.42:274][658]LogWindows: Error:  
[2020.05.18-12.43.42:274][658]LogWindows: Error:  
[2020.05.18-12.43.42:274][658]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff9d353a799 KERNELBASE.dll!UnknownFunction [] 
[2020.05.18-12.43.42:274][658]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff96567a7b6 UE4Editor-Core.dll!UnknownFunction [] 
[2020.05.18-12.43.42:274][658]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff96567dc58 UE4Editor-Core.dll!UnknownFunction [] 
[2020.05.18-12.43.42:274][658]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff965432c7d UE4Editor-Core.dll!UnknownFunction [] 
[2020.05.18-12.43.42:274][658]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff9653bfd43 UE4Editor-Core.dll!UnknownFunction [] 
[2020.05.18-12.43.42:274][658]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff9653c20c0 UE4Editor-Core.dll!UnknownFunction [] 
[2020.05.18-12.43.42:274][658]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff9a8aa6bc7 UE4Editor-xx-0001.dll!TBitArray<FDefaultBitArrayAllocator>::Add() [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.24\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Containers\BitArray.h:346] 
[2020.05.18-12.43.42:274][658]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff9a8aa2b7d UE4Editor-xx-0001.dll!TSet<TTuple<FString,TArray<unsigned char,TSizedDefaultAllocator<32> >
    >,TDefaultMapHashableKeyFuncs<FString,TArray<unsigned char,TSizedDefaultAllocator<32>
    >,0>,FDefaultSetAllocator>::Emplace<TPairInitializer<FString const &,TArray<unsigned char,TSizedDefaultAllocator<32> > const &> >() [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.24\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Containers\Set.h:588] 
[2020.05.18-12.43.42:274][658]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff9a8aa8619 UE4Editor-xx-0001.dll!Classname::OnImageDataReceived() [C:dir/file.cpp:180]
```

Comment: Why don't you use a critical section here? Do you have only one thread accessing the map at a time?

Comment: I think I am accessing the map from the game thread as well as the callback-thread. (Defining the Map in the Game Thread and adding value in callback-thread.) I was not aware of the critical section, reading about it rn. If you know any tutorials of the critical section with usage examples, please share. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You accessing your map from two threads at the same time, so you have a data race.
UE4 has `FCriticalSection` class that wraps platform mutex. Just wrap you accesses with `FScopeLock` like this:

```
FCriticalSection URLToImageTArrayDictionaryCS;
TMap<FString, TArray<uint8>> URLToImageTArrayDictionary;

OnImageDataReceived(FHttpRequestPtr Request, FHttpResponsePtr Response, bool bWasSuccessful)
{
    if (bWasSuccessful && Response.IsValid())
    {
        FString key = "key";
        TArray<uint8> IntArray;
        IntArray.Init(10, 5);

        {
            FScopeLock Lock(&URLToImageTArrayDictionaryCS);
            URLToImageTArrayDictionary.Add(key, IntArray); //This crashes with error given log
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting a EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION  at FScopeLock Lock line itself. I have Declarations on file.h and FScopeLock just as you have put in OnImageDataReceived(). any ideas?

Comment: I used profiler and breakpoints to see if the OnImageDataReceived() is happening on other thread, found out it is happening on MainThread. I am unsure of the problem entirely right now.

Comment: Hm... Are you sure your object is alive when the callback is called? How do you create it?

Comment: The destructor of the object is called before callback methods, so the object is no more alive. I will try using "new" & "delete" keywords to mange the object Or use shared pointers.

Comment: hey @Michael, Using TSharedRef to create the object is working for me. Thank you. This resolves my question completely.

Answer (score 0):

The crash was caused by the fact that I was referring to the dictionary after the object (which the dictionary was the private variable of) was destroyed.

Using TSharedRef and keeping the object valid fixed this. [Documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/SmartPointerLibrary/SharedReference/index.html)